# c# get min, max and average from list<object>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Order>`

```
public class Order
{
   public Order()
   {
   }

   public string UserId {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to get the following information using LINQ:

- the `UserId` that has the most orders
- the `UserId` that has the least orders
- the average of all orders

So the result should be something like:

- UserId: 1 has 20 orders (max)
- UserId: 2 has 5 orders (min)
- Average 12.5 orders

Comment: Min, Max and average of what? The only data you have is a string and you cannot average strings. (There are lots of great tutorials on LINQ out there: what have you done to learn LINQ? [SO] is not a tutorial.)

Comment: Min, Max and average of orders ...

Comment: Right, but what information from `Order` would you like the Max, Min and Average of? What have you already tried? And why does it not work for you? As said, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx, if you have questions after that, feel free to ask them here.

Comment: Group the orders per userid and then count the grouping or something like that ...

Comment: How did User 3 manage to get half an order? o_O

Comment: @Corak: my bad that's the average not user 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Lookup`:

```
var userLookup = orderList.ToLookup(o => o.UserId);
int maxOrders = userLookup.Max(x => x.Count());
int minOrders = userLookup.Min(x => x.Count());
int avgOrders = (int)userLookup.Average(x => x.Count());
IEnumerable<string> allUserIDsWithMaxOrders = userLookup
    .Where(x => x.Count() == maxOrders)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
IEnumerable<string> allUserIDsWithMinOrders = userLookup
    .Where(x => x.Count() == minOrders)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
IEnumerable<string> allUserIDsWithAvgOrders = userLookup
    .Where(x => x.Count() == avgOrders)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

However, it's not clear to me how you want to get the average order-count of a single user, isn't that always an absolute value?

Comment: Note that the OP is probably wanting the Median instead of the Average; it makes no sense at all to find the 'ids with average'.

Comment: @Bas: i' ve been asking myself the same question and added that as comment to my answer. So treat the average-part of the question as open. Maybe the answer is helpful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create groups by userId and work with them.

```
var groups = allOrders.GroupBy(o => o.UserId);
int userWithMostOrders = groups.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key;
double averageOrders = allOrders.Count() / groups.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userWithLeastOrders = ordens.GroupBy(o => o.UserId)
                                .OrderBy(group => group.Count())
                                .First()
                                .Key;
```

You should be able to work out the others.

Comment: But what if muliple users have the same order-count? Also, `Max` returns an int which has no `Key` property.

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, I've fixed my answer, thanks. As for what should happen when multiple users have the same order count, the OP didn't tell us what should happen, so it's fair to assume he wants any *one* of those users.